# I need access to the password grant type of OAUTH2

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I work for a large company and we are developing an app that needs access to a token without a web browser interface. Reason for this is that we have a technical limitation where we cannot present a secondary keyboard to a user for them to enter their google credentials. We can present a keyboard for user verification at the device.

The authorization is the first step of OAuth2, the service implemented OAuth2 usually will popup browser to ask user login and consent,  for example, to access Google APIs, no matter the type of application, we application, mobile applications, etc., the authorization will be accomplished by user’s login and consent through popup. This is not we are looking for.

OAuth2 also provides a “password” grant type which can be used to exchange a username and password for an access token directly without redirect (popup).   This is also what we are looking for from Google. However, there is no any information of this type of OAuth from Google official developers site.

Is there someone that can help with this?

Comment: Google Oauth requires a user to grant their permission using a browser. However that can be done separately from the app itself. Depending on the details of your environment, maybe that helps.

Comment: Could you provide a sample on how this can be done?  Is there documentation?  Where we are struggling is how the permission that is done in a separately is fed back to the original app.

Comment: I've posted this as an answer as it's easier to format. See below

Answer (score 1):

Google does not offer the password grant type and is unlikely to ever do so.

If your application is dedicated to Google Apps users, you can create a service account and have the administrator of the domain to whitelist it for a set of APIs. For more details see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount and https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106

Comment: For a service account seems like it allows an application to access a google api without user information.  But we need to access the users information on behalf of a user.  Do you have any other suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, maybe you can do the auth in a separate app. The flow would look something like this

1. Create a web page which prompts the user for his auth, and request offline access.
2. One time only, on a PC of his choice, the User vists that page and gives his auth. You   now have a refresh token for that user, which you will store (probably on a server)
3. Your app needs access to that refresh token, so once your user authenticates himself, the app can retrieve the refresh token, convert it to an access token, and Robert is your father's brother